# How to implement a single-value cache in RxJava 3?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

- Kotlin `1.3.+`
- RxJava `3.0.+`
- Kotest `4.1.+`

```
// SingleValueCache.kt
package com.example

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference

abstract class SingleValueCache<V> {
    protected abstract fun retrieve(): Single<V>
    protected abstract fun validate(cached: V): Single<Boolean>

    private inner class Cached(val version: Int, val value: V)

    private val mutex: Semaphore = Semaphore(1)
    private val cached: AtomicReference<Cached> = AtomicReference()

    fun get(): Single<V> =
        Single.defer { cached.get() ?.let(::existing) ?: initial() }.map { it.value }

    private fun initial(): Single<Cached> = retrieve(1)

    private fun existing(cached: Cached): Single<Cached> =
        validate(cached.value).concatMap { valid ->
            if (valid)
                Single.just(cached)
            else
                retrieve(cached.version + 1)
        }

    private fun retrieve(version: Int): Single<Cached> = Single.defer {
        val unlock: () -> Unit = lock()
        val curr = cached.get()?.takeIf { it.version >= version }

        when (curr) {
            null ->
                retrieve()
                    .map { v ->
                        Cached(version, v).also { fresh ->
                            cached.set(fresh)
                            unlock()
                        }
                    }
                    .doOnDispose { unlock() }
                    .doOnError { unlock() }
            else ->
                Single.just(curr).also { unlock() }
        }
    }

    private fun lock(): () -> Unit {
        mutex.acquire()
        // i've observed some strange scenarios where the lock was released more than once,
        // which is why the AtomicBoolean is being used here -
        // to make absolutely sure that the lock is released *exactly* once
        val locked = AtomicBoolean(true)

        return {
            val wasLocked = locked.getAndSet(false)
            if (wasLocked)
                mutex.release()
        }
    }
}
```

```
// SingleValueCacheTest.kt
package com.example

import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FreeSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Completable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

class SingleValueCacheTest : FreeSpec() {
    companion object {
        fun setup(): Pair<SingleValueCache<Int>, () -> Unit> {
            val target = AtomicInteger(1)

            val cache: SingleValueCache<Int> = object : SingleValueCache<Int>() {
                val curr = AtomicInteger(0)
                override fun retrieve(): Single<Int> = Single.fromCallable { curr.incrementAndGet() }
                override fun validate(cached: Int): Single<Boolean> = Single.just(cached == target.get())
            }

            return Pair(cache, { target.incrementAndGet() ; Unit })
        }
    }

    init {
        "get" {
            val (cache, invalidate) = setup()
            val (par, trials) = (10 to 100)

            val trial = Flowable
                .fromCallable { cache.get() }
                .repeat(par.toLong())
                .parallel(par, 1)
                    .runOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMap { it.toFlowable() }
                .sequential()

            val results = trial
                .concatWith(Completable.fromCallable { invalidate() })
                .repeat(trials.toLong())
                .toList()
                .blockingGet()

            results shouldBe ((1..trials).flatMap { v -> (1..par).map { v } })
        }
    }
}
```

The above seems to work well, but I'm a bit concerned about correctly releasing the lock in edge cases. Specifically, is calling `unlock()` sufficient in the `doOnError` and `doOnDispose`? I haven't been able to find any detailed docs around the lifecycle and proper places for releasing resources - there are many `doOn*` variations and, personally, I find it confusing to understand how to use those callbacks correctly and effectively.